# How to unpack a list of tuple in various length in a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
ID LIST_OF_TUPLE (2col)
1   [('2012','12'), ('2012','33'), ('2014', '82')]
2   NA
3   [('2012','12')]
4   [('2012','12'), ('2012','33'), ('2014', '82'), ('2022', '67')]
```

Result:

```
ID TUP_1 TUP_2(3col)
1  2012   12
1  2012   33
1  2014   82
3  2012   12
4  2012   12
4  2012   33
4  2014   82
4  2022   67
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks Alollz for the formatting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `explode` then create a dataframe and then `join`:

```
s = df['LIST_OF_TUPLE'].explode()
out = (df[['ID']].join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index)
        .add_prefix("TUP_")).reset_index(drop=True)) #you can chain a dropna if reqd
```

---

```
print(out)

   ID TUP_0 TUP_1
0   1  2012    12
1   1  2012    33
2   1  2014    82
3   2   NaN  None
4   3  2012    12
5   4  2012    12
6   4  2012    33
7   4  2014    82
8   4  2022    67
```

Comment: Thanks Anky, however, I'm not getting the same results. I'm getting the tup_0 as a list of all the tuple from the original

Comment: @Leo may be the values are not lists then but a string representation of lists. check dtype once and convert to list from string for this to work

Comment: my dtype says it's 'o', but when i loop it it turns to float for Nan or (str). How best can I convert everything to a list?

Comment: @Leo you can try doing `import ast` , then `df['LIST_OF_TUPLE'] = df['LIST_OF_TUPLE'].dropna().apply(ast.literal_eval)` , then try my solution